# KeystoneJS not auto-compiling LESS files to CSS

Tags: keystonejs

In KeystoneJS [Docs](https://keystonejs.com/documentation/configuration/server-options/), it mentions that upon requesting `style.min.css` from the server, this will compile `style.less` and generate `style.min.css` in production.

> If you want Keystone to automatically compile .less files into .css files, set this value to the same path as the static option.

I have followed this and I have added some LESS code in `style.less` but my changes are not reflected in `style.min.css`, in other words, the file `style.min.css` is not regenerated, I am not sure if it's a bug or am I missing something.

For ease of example to reproduce, I just added this code in `styles/site.less`:

```
html {
    background: black !important;
}
```

I expect the whole background to be black, but it's not working.

```
Keystone config:
let keystone = require('keystone');

keystone = keystone.init({
    'mongo': process.env.MONGO_URI
    'name': 'CMS',
    'brand': 'CMS',

    'less': 'public',
    'static': 'public',
    'favicon': 'public/favicon.ico',
    'views': 'templates/views',
    'view engine': 'pug',

    'auto update': true,
    'session': true,
    'auth': true,
    'user model': 'User',
});

keystone.import('models');

keystone.set('locals', {
    _: require('lodash'),
    env: keystone.get('env'),
    utils: keystone.utils,
    editable: keystone.content.editable,
});

keystone.set('signin logo', '../images/logo.png');

// Load your project's Routes
keystone.set('routes', require('./routes'));

// Configure the navigation bar in Keystone's Admin UI
keystone.set('nav', {
    users: 'users',
    intents: 'intents',
    Items: ['categories', 'sub-categories', 'products'],
    messages: 'messages',
});

keystone.start();
```

Comment: can you share your keystone config section

Answer (score 0):

this is what i did and it works well

- update generator to latest version
- create new website with `yo keystone`
- start website by using `node keystone`
- change public/styles/site.less with changes what you did (black background)
- refresh the page